# Change image in specified div when checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am wanting to display an image in a div when checkboxes or buttons are selected. I need to to be able to select multiple boxes and display a different image based on the total selection.

The selection matrix would be as follows: A, B, C, D, AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, ABC, ABD. C and D cannot appear together. When nothing is selected I want it to display image F.

I was also hoping to use Bootstrap styling to make them look like buttons not checkboxes.

```
<div>
    <form name="test1"> 
        <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group itemcontent">
            <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="myimages" value="01" id="myimages" onclick="check_value(1)" />Selector1</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="myimages" value="02" id="myimages" onclick="check_value(2)" />Selector2</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="myimages" value="03" id="myimages" onclick="check_value(3)" />Selector3</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="myimages" value="04" id="myimages" onclick="check_value(4)" />Selector4</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

I was thinking of using a script like this:

```
function check_value(fieldvalue)
{    
    switch(fieldvalue)
    {
        case 1:

            document.getElementById("imagetest").innerHTML = "<img src='img/600/600T_W_Base_Model.png'>";
                break;

        case 2:

            document.getElementById("imagetest").innerHTML = "<img src='img/600/600T_W_DW.png'>"; 
                break;
```

For my image display div:`<div class="col-6" id="imagetest"></div>`

But I'm honestly not sure where to go from here. I'm VERY new to JavaScript.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

With a friends help we were able to come up with a test, but I can't get the code to work correctly...

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
        <title>Test </title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.../jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.../jque.../1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.../jqu.../1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.../3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.../3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
        input {
        display: none;
        }

        input:checked ~ label {
        background: #00C000;
        border: 1px solid #090;
        color: #fff;
        }

        label {
        background: #ddd;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        /* Konqueror */
        -moz-user-select: none;
        /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none;
        /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none;
        /* Non-prefixed version, currently
        not supported by any browser */
        padding: 10px 30px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        color: #555;
        }
        </style>
        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="form1">
        <form name="test">
        <span><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" onchange="check_value()" data-val="A"><label for="chk1">A</label></span>
        <span><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" onchange="check_value()" data-val="B"><label for="chk2">B</label></span>
        <span><input type="checkbox" id="chk3" onchange="check_value()" data-val="C"><label for="chk3">C</label></span>
        <span><input type="checkbox" id="chk4" onchange="check_value()" data-val="D"><label for="chk4">D</label></span>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div id="imagetest" style="height:200px;width: 200px; border: 5px solid red;"> 
        </div>
        </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function check_value()
        {
        var myVal = '';
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function()
        {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
        myVal += $(this).data('val');
        }
        });

        alert(myVal);

        var myDiv = $('#imagetest');
        if (myVal == 'A')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'blue');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'B')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'green');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'C')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'grey');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'D')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'pink');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'AB')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'orange');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'AC')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'yellow');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'AD')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'black');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'BC')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'lightblue');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'BD')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'ABC')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'brown');
        }
        else if (myVal == 'ABD')
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'Cyan');
        }
        else
        {
        myDiv.css('background-color', 'white');
        }
        }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        input {
        display: none;
        }

        input:checked ~ label {
        background: #00C000;
        border: 1px solid #090;
        color: #fff;
        }

        label {
        background: #ddd;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        /* Konqueror */
        -moz-user-select: none;
        /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none;
        /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none;
        /* Non-prefixed version, currently
        not supported by any browser */
        padding: 10px 30px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        color: #555;
        }
        </style>

        </html>
```

What am I doing wrong here..?

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cq1qg6wy/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it you want to change image in radio-button selection. If you want to select multiple radio-button you must use another type, checkbox.

## Vanilla JavaScript

This is a vanilla, pure javascript, code:

```js
function changeImage(elem) {
  var imageUrl = elem.getAttribute('image');
  document.getElementById('imgview').setAttribute('src', imageUrl);
}
document.querySelector('[value="one"]').click();
```

```html
<div id="form1">
  <form name='test'>
    <span><input onclick="changeImage(this)" type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/300/200" name="field" value="one">BASE</span>
    <span><input onclick="changeImage(this)" type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/300/300" name="field" value="two">Deep Well </span>
    <span><input onclick="changeImage(this)" type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/200/200" name="field" value="three">Extension </span>
    <span><input onclick="changeImage(this)" type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/200/300" name="field" value="four">Treadmill</span>
    <span><input onclick="changeImage(this)" type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/300/250" name="field" value="five">Stairs </span>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="imagetest">
    <img id="imgview" src="">
</div>
```

Simple explanation:

You give every radio button an attribute with the link (relative or absolute is your choice) and then in the function call grep the value for that attribute for the clicked element and set it as image element source.

## jQuery

If you want to use jQuery to accomplish it this is a sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#form1 input[name=field][value]').on('click', function(e) {
    var imageUrl = $(this).attr('image');
    $('#imgview').attr('src', imageUrl);
  });

  $('#form1 input[name=field][value=one]').click();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form1">
  <form name='test'>
    <span><input type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/300/200" name="field" value="one">BASE</span>
    <span><input type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/300/300" name="field" value="two">Deep Well </span>
    <span><input type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/200/200" name="field" value="three">Extension </span>
    <span><input type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/200/300" name="field" value="four">Treadmill</span>
    <span><input type="radio" image="https://placebear.com/300/250" name="field" value="five">Stairs </span>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="imagetest">
  <img id="imgview" src="">
</div>
```

Edit:

Multiple selection with multiple image view

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#form1 input[name=field][value]').on('click', function(e) {
    var imageUrl = $(this).attr('image');
    var fieldValue = $(this).val();
    var idImage = 'image_' + fieldValue;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#imagetest').append('<img src="' + imageUrl + '" id="' + idImage + '">');
    } else {
   $('#'+idImage).remove();
    }

  });

  $('#form1 input[name=field][value=one]').click();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form1">
  <form name='test'>
    <label><input type="checkbox" image="https://placebear.com/300/200" name="field" value="one">BASE</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" image="https://placebear.com/300/300" name="field" value="two">Deep Well </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" image="https://placebear.com/200/200" name="field" value="three">Extension </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" image="https://placebear.com/200/300" name="field" value="four">Treadmill</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" image="https://placebear.com/300/250" name="field" value="five">Stairs </label>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="imagetest">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is fantastic! Now, I am going to need to have multiples selected, I suppose that radio inputs is where I was going wrong in the firstplace. I tried changing the type to checkbox, but it (and I figured it wouldn't) come up with a different image all together. So to say, selecting A or B is good but AB doesn't return a different image, just the last "checked".

Comment: This becouse the logic needs a different approach. Are you able to get it?